# Gulp Vinyl FTP ECONNRESET error after FEAT command

Tags: ftp, gulp

I am attempting to use the gulp-vinyl-ftp plugin to upload to a remote site.

```
gulp.task("deploy", ["default"], function () {

    var conn = ftp.create({
        host: "mywebsite",
        user: "****",
        password: "******",
       // secure: true,
      timeOffset: -301,
       parallel: 1,
       debug: gutil.log
    });    

    var globs = [
        "distr/**/*.php",
        "!out/vendor/**",
        "!out/config.php",
        "out/**/*.map",
        "out/**/*.css",
        "out/**/*.js"
    ];
    return gulp.src(globs)
        .pipe(conn.newer("/")).pipe(debug({ title: "Deploy New: " }))

});
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1016:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:609:25)
```

The debug output is as follows:

```
[08:37:28] [connection] < '220 Microsoft FTP Service\r\n'
[08:37:28] [parser] < '220 Microsoft FTP Service\r\n'
[08:37:28] [parser] Response: code=220, buffer='Microsoft FTP Service'
[08:37:28] [connection] > 'USER xxx'
[08:37:29] [connection] < '331 Password required\r\n'
[08:37:29] [parser] < '331 Password required\r\n'
[08:37:29] [parser] Response: code=331, buffer='Password required'
[08:37:29] [connection] > 'PASS xxxx'
[08:37:29] [connection] < '230 User logged in.\r\n'
[08:37:29] [parser] < '230 User logged in.\r\n'
[08:37:29] [parser] Response: code=230, buffer='User logged in.'
[08:37:29] [connection] > 'FEAT'
```

It ends there.

However, I can connect just fine through WinSCP.

```
. 2017-11-08 08:36:24.161 Connecting to mywebsite ...
. 2017-11-08 08:36:24.192 Connected with  mywebsite. Waiting for welcome message...
< 2017-11-08 08:36:24.285 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2017-11-08 08:36:24.285 USER xxxx
< 2017-11-08 08:36:24.379 331 Password required
> 2017-11-08 08:36:25.861 PASS ********
< 2017-11-08 08:36:25.970 230 User logged in.
> 2017-11-08 08:36:25.970 SYST
. 2017-11-08 08:36:26.064 The server is probably running Windows, assuming that directory listing timestamps are affected by DST.
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.064 215 Windows_NT
> 2017-11-08 08:36:26.064 FEAT
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157 211-Extended features supported:
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  LANG EN*
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  UTF8
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  PBSZ
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  PROT C;P;
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  CCC
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  HOST
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  SIZE
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  MDTM
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157  REST STREAM
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157 211 END
> 2017-11-08 08:36:26.157 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2017-11-08 08:36:26.251 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
. 2017-11-08 08:36:26.298 Connected
```

I have tried both the IP address and domain name in the host field, commenting out the the timeOffset and parallel options.

I am not sure where to go from here honestly; any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will find lot of posts about IIS mysteriously (and inconsistently) closing a connection after receiving `FEAT` command.

I have not found any definitive solution, but working workaround seems to be to deny the `FEAT` command (if Gulp can handle that).

In IIS manager, go to *FTP > FTP Request Filtering > Commands tab > Actions > Deny command* and type `FEAT`.

See also [Microsoft FTP fails to connect after the client requests the list of features (FEAT)](https://serverfault.com/q/163362/168875).

Comment: Thanks much. Unfortunately, my access to the server is quite limited for this website, but I will see what I can do. Thanks much for at least pointing me in the proper direction; I would not have suspected an "oddity" with IIS to be a contributory factor.